# Fancy header wrong header width

Tags: fancyhdr, geometry, octavo

I'm having some problems with the width of fancyhdr. Using this code:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{octavo}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
    \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
    \fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\footnotesize\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
    \fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\footnotesize\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
    \setlength{\headheight}{15pt} 

\geometry{papersize={170mm, 240mm}}
          
\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

my header is like this:

[image]

The line separating the header from the body is too short and the number is not in the corner.

Where am I going wrong? I've used this piece of `fancyhdr` code several time and never had this issue.

Comment: Set `papersize` before `\pagestyle{fancy}`.

Comment: @esdd this solved the problem. If you write it as answer I mark it to be the solution.